# Rails filterrific not updating view after selection a filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, filterrific

I am trying to add filterrific to my rails app. I followed [this](http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/) tutorial but my live update is not working. I need to hit refresh to update the results in my view.
I tried looking for solution and found some links ([Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736417/view-is-not-updating-after-applying-filter-ruby-rails-filterrific), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402011/rails-filterrific-live-update-not-working)), but no success. Below is my code.

agent.rb

```
class Agent < ApplicationRecord
  STATUS_ACTIVE = 'ACTIVE'.freeze
  STATUS_INACTIVE = 'INACTIVE'.freeze

  filterrific(
      default_filter_params: { sorted_by: 'name_asc' },
      available_filters: [
          :sorted_by,
          :search_query,
          :with_agent_id,
      ]
  )

  scope :sorted_by, lambda { |sort_option|
    direction = /desc$/.match?(sort_option) ? "desc" : "asc"
    case sort_option.to_s
    when /^name/
      order("name #{direction}")
    when /^location/
      order("location #{direction}")
    else
      raise(ArgumentError, "Invalid sort option: #{sort_option.inspect}")
    end
  }
  scope :search_query, lambda { |query|
    # Filters students whose name or email matches the query
  }
  scope :with_agent_id, lambda { |agent_ids|
    where(id: agent_ids)
  }

  # This method provides select options for the `sorted_by` filter select input.
  # It is called in the controller as part of `initialize_filterrific`.
  def self.options_for_sorted_by
    [
        ["Name (a-z)", "name_asc"],
        ["Name (z-a)", "name_desc"],
        ["Location (a-z)", "location_asc"],
    ]
  end
end
```

AgentsController/index.html.erb

```
def index
    @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
        Agent,
        params[:filterrific],
        select_options: {
            sorted_by: Agent.options_for_sorted_by,
        },
        persistence_id: true,
        default_filter_params: {},
        available_filters: [:sorted_by],
        sanitize_params: true,
        ) || return

    @agents = @filterrific.find.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for_filterrific @filterrific do |f| %>
  <div>
    Search
    <%= f.text_field(
            :search_query,
            class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed'
        ) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    Sorted by
    <%= f.select(:sorted_by, @filterrific.select_options[:sorted_by]) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= link_to(
            'Reset filters',
            reset_filterrific_url,
            ) %>
  </div>
  <%# add an automated spinner to your form when the list is refreshed %>
  <%= render_filterrific_spinner %>
<% end %>

<%= render(
        partial: 'agents/list',
        locals: { agents: @agents }
    ) %>
```

_list.html.erb (partial)

```
<div id="filterrific_results">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= filterrific_sorting_link(@filterrific, :name) %></th>
      <th><%= filterrific_sorting_link(@filterrific, :location) %></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <% agents.each do |agent| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= agent.name %></td>
        <td><%= agent.location %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<%= will_paginate agents %>
```

logs

```
Started GET "/agents?filterrific%5Bsorted_by%5D=location_desc" for ::1 at 2020-03-12 16:26:07 +0530
Processing by AgentsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"filterrific"=>{"sorted_by"=>"location_desc"}}
  User Load (301.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/agents_controller.rb:107:in `authenticate_user'
  Rendering agents/index.js.erb
  Agent Load (248.2ms)  SELECT "agents".* FROM "agents" ORDER BY location desc LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  ↳ app/views/agents/_list.html.erb:20
  Rendered agents/_list.html.erb (Duration: 255.6ms | Allocations: 1562)
  Rendered agents/index.js.erb (Duration: 268.5ms | Allocations: 5750)
Completed 200 OK in 585ms (Views: 27.3ms | ActiveRecord: 550.0ms | Allocations: 8947)
```

Comment: probably add some logs to see what rails is responding with ?

Comment: Started GET "/agents?filterrific%5Bsorted_by%5D=name_asc" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-03-07 12:16:25 +0530
Processing by AgentsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"filterrific"=>{"sorted_by"=>"name_asc"}}
  User Load (240.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Comment: Rendering agents/index.js.erb
  Agent Load (240.0ms)  SELECT "agents".* FROM "agents" ORDER BY name asc LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  ↳ app/views/agents/_list.html.erb:20
  Rendered agents/_list.html.erb (Duration: 247.9ms | Allocations: 1540)
  Rendered agents/index.js.erb (Duration: 253.6ms | Allocations: 5604)
Completed 200 OK in 503ms

Comment: So you can see, rails server is working fine

Comment: please update your question and add logs in a cleaner way so its easier to read.

Comment: Updated (added rails server logs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add some javascript in order to live update your result. Can you add the following code as `index.js.erb` along side with `index.html.erb`

```js
<% js = escape_javascript(
  render(partial: agents/list, locals: { agents: @agents })
) %>
$("#filterrific_results").html("<%= js %>");
```

Comment: Thank. It works. Earlier also I tried but it did not work. Now its working.